# Select all rows from 2 tables where field =?

Tags: php, mysql

Quite simply, I need an MySQL statement that selects all the rows from 2 different tables `where userId = 1`. Here's the statement I have but it doesn't work. It returns results from table 1 (The left table):

```
$transactionsQ = $db->query("select e.sender, e.amount, e.timestamp, s.sender, s.recipient, s.amount, s.timestamp from ethTransactions as e, sofTransactions as s where e.userId = ? or s.userId = ?", [$currentUser->id, $currentUser->id]);
```

table1 (ethTransactions) is like:

`|id|userId|sender|amount|timestamp|`

table2 (sofTransactions) is like:

`|id|userId|sender|recipient|amount|timestamp|`

some data on ethTransactions:

`1|12|ajdoaidjoiwjdaq|0.03222|2017-11-08 03:09:11`

some data on sofTransactions:

`1|12|opiyptropyirpyi|dqwuebhdnwq|1.02223|2017-10-08 04:09:11`

What I want to return since both have the same userId:

```
|id|userId|sender         |recipient  |amount |timestamp          |
|1 |12    |ajdoaidjoiwjdaq|           |0.03222|2017-11-08 03:09:11|
|1 |12    |opiyptropyirpyi|dqwuebhdnwq|1.02223|2017-10-08 04:09:11|
```

Comment: what is the other table name?

Comment: Provide both tables structure please

Comment: what database engine are you using?

Comment: question edited

Comment: This is working but need to sort them altogether: `select sender, null as recipient, amount, \`timestamp\` from ethTransactions where userId = ? union all select sender, recipient, amount, \`timestamp\` from sofTransactions where userId = ?`

Answer (score 2):

You should use [LEFT JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) to do that.

```
  SELECT 
      e.sender as e_sender, 
      e.amount as e_amount, 
      e.timestamp as e_timestamp, 
      s.sender as s_sender, 
      s.recipient as s_recipient, 
      s.amount as s_amount, 
      s.timestamp as as_timestamp 
  FROM 
      ethTransactions e 
  LEFT JOIN 
      sofTransactions s ON s.userId = e.userId 
  WHERE 
      e.userId = ?
```

Comment: He is just showing an alternative way to do it. But what you are trying to do is combining 2 tables with a userId relation. The best way would be to use innerJoin

Comment: @YouneL +1 yes of course, I have just copied and modified. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: I implemented it but it's only returning the results from `sofTransactions` now: `select e.sender, e.amount, e.timestamp, s.sender, s.recipient, s.amount, s.timestamp from ethTransactions e inner join sofTransactions s on s.userId = e.userId where e.userId = ?`

Comment: because both tables have the same columnnames. You have to define a new name for the columns. I have updated my answer. You can use recipient without prefix "s_" or with prefix.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks. Can you sort of elaborate verbosely on what each thing is doing after `INNER_JOIN`? It seems like `sofTransactions s` is setting up `s` as a reference for those columns. What I don't fully understand is `ON`, `=`, `WHERE` and their relationships to each other in this context.

Comment: s and e are the aliases of the tables

Comment: oh and `ON s.userId = e.userId`, that's just a comparison operation for the join but then why `e.userId`? Could it have also been `s.userId`?

Comment: ON is the condition type,  e.userId = s.userId is the condition that creates a relation between two tables.

Comment: This isn't right. I didn't want to join them. I simply want the rows from both tables where the userId's are the same.

Comment: All you have to do is switching the `INNER JOIN`to `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_names(s) FROM table1 AS t1 **INNER JOIN** table2 AS t2
ON t1.userId = t2.userId WHERE t1.userId=1;
```

Comment: Code only answers may provide the answer to the problem, but an explanation helps a lot in understanding what you've changed and why it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is something strange about the structure of your database. A JOIN on userid seems natural, but it potentially joins rows from one table with rows from the other table that have different sender columns. This would imply that you are joining data items that do not belong together.

My answer to your question is: redesign your table structure because you are going to break one of the main rules of relational databases - most likely, duplicating data.

Comment: the sender column doesn't matter for what I'm doing. there will never be a duplicate transaction. these 2 tables are 2 different currencies the user has access to from the site. I see what you're saying but when a transaction is sent, it's only recorded once in 1 table.

Comment: That still doesn't explain joining them together. You will end up with ALL your user's transactions in one table joined to ALL his/her transactions in the other table. The correct way is to normalise the data entities before making tables.